# MongoDB, Aggregate,group and project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to make a query that returns the amount of comments each different blogtype has `("bloggtyp: "recept"/ "mina böcker" / "övrigt")`.

The output result should be something like

```
{
    "bloggtyp": "recept", 
    "kommentarer" : 7, 
    "bloggtyp": "mina böcker", 
    "kommentarer" : 1, 
    "bloggtyp": "övrigt", 
    "kommentarer" : 1
}
```

My current query only returns the total amount of comments for all `blogtypes`:

```
db.morgan.aggregate(
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: "", 
            kommentarer: { $sum: "$kommentarer" }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0, 
            kommentarer: "$kommentarer"
        }
    }
)
```

So what is the correct syntax to project amount of comments for each bloggtype?

```
{
    "bloggtyp": "recept",
    "rubrik": "MOROTSSOPPA",
    "gillar": 17,
    "kommentarer": 3,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    },{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-13",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "keeo"
    },{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-11",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "madad"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2012 - 04 - 23",
    "taggar": ["morötter", "soppa", "förrätter"],
    "tid": {
        "tillagning": 5,
        "på spisen": 30
    },
    "img": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >",
    "instruktioner": "Gör sa här: Skala morötterna – med din kropp! Koka i buljong.Salta och peppra efter tycke och smak.",

    "ingredienser": [{
        "typ": "Morötter",
        "gram": 500,
        "kcal/100g": 41
    }, {
        "typ": "buljong",
        "dl": 10,
        "kcal/100g": 128
    }, {
        "typ": "salt",
        "tsk": 1,
        "kcal/100g": 0
    }, {
        "typ": "peppar",
        "tsk": 1,
        "kcal/100g": 0
    }]
}

    {
    "bloggtyp": "recept",
    "rubrik": "BARKBROED MED TOMATSALSA",
    "gillar": 0,
    "kommentarer": 1,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2016 - 10 - 20",
    "taggar": ["broed", "tomater", "såser"],
    "tid": {
        "tillagning": 20,
        "på spisen": 30
    },
    "img": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >",
    "instruktioner": "Gör sa här: Blanda ihop allt. Knada. Baka i 200 grader i 30minuter eller tills de fått smarrig, fin färg.",

    "ingredienser": [{
            "typ": "rågmjöl",
            "dl": 3.5,
            "kcal/100g": 44
        }, {
            "typ": "salt",
            "tsk": 1,
            "kcal/100g": 0
        }, {
            "typ": "hemgnagt barkmjöl",
            "dl": 1.5,
            "kcal/100g": 96
        }, {
            "typ": "vatten",
            "dl": 2,
            "kcal/100g": 0
        }, {
            "typ": "tomatsalsa på burk",
            "st": 1,
            "kcal/100g": 699
        }

    ]
}
 {
    "bloggtyp": "recept",
    "rubrik": "PADTHAI",
    "gillar": 0,
    "kommentarer": 1,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2016 - 11 - 20",
    "taggar": ["thai", "mat", "gott"],
    "tid": {
        "tillagning": 5,
        "på spisen": 10
    },
    "img": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >",
    "instruktioner": "Gör så här: sätt värmen på 300grader och blanda alla ingredienser",

    "ingredienser": [{
            "typ": "toa nga",
            "dl": 5,
            "kcal/100g": 144
        }, {
            "typ": "salt",
            "tsk": 4,
            "kcal/100g": 0
        }, {
            "typ": "thai sås",
            "dl": 2,
            "kcal/100g": 96
        }, {
            "typ": "vatten",
            "dl": 2,
            "kcal/100g": 0
        }, {
            "typ": "tomatsalsa på burk",
            "st": 1,
            "kcal/100g": 699
        }

    ]
}
  {
    "bloggtyp": "recept",
    "rubrik": "kyckling panang",
    "gillar": 0,
    "kommentarer": 1,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2016 - 9 - 20",
    "taggar": ["thai", "mat", "bra"],
    "tid": {
        "tillagning": 6,
        "på spisen": 11
    },
    "img": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >",
    "instruktioner": "Gör så här: sätt värmen på 300grader och blanda alla ingredienser",

    "ingredienser": [{
            "typ": "toa nga",
            "dl": 5,
            "kcal/100g": 144
        }, {
            "typ": "salt",
            "tsk": 4,
            "kcal/100g": 0
        }, {
            "typ": "thai sås",
            "dl": 2,
            "kcal/100g": 96
        }

    ]
}
 {
    "bloggtyp": "recept",
    "rubrik": "tom yam soup",
    "gillar": 0,
    "kommentarer": 1,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2016 - 8 - 20",
    "taggar": ["thai", "mat", "dåligt"],
    "tid": {
        "tillagning": 6,
        "på spisen": 12
    },
    "img": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >",
    "instruktioner": "Gör så här: sätt värmen på 300grader och blanda alla ingredienser",

    "ingredienser": [{
            "typ": "böngroddar",
            "dl": 5,
            "kcal/100g": 198
        }, {
            "typ": "salt",
            "tsk": 4,
            "kcal/100g": 12
        }, {
            "typ": "thai sås",
            "dl": 2,
            "kcal/100g": 444
        }

    ]
}
 {
    "bloggtyp": "mina böcker",
    "rubrik": "självinsikt",
    "gillar": 0,
    "kommentarer": 1,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2016 - 8 - 20",
    "taggar": ["raw", "veggo", "varmrätter"],
    "img": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >",
    "om boken": "denna är jättebra bok, kul"


}
 {
    "bloggtyp": "övrigt",
    "rubrik": "deprimerad",
    "gillar": 33,
    "kommentarer": 1,
    "kommentar": [{
        "kommentartid": "2016-12-12",
        "rubrik": "hej",
        "textkommentar": "jättefinblogg",
        "nickname": "liam"
    }],
    "timestamp": "2016 - 7 - 20",
    "taggar": ["knyppling", "prozac", "hjälp"],
    "img": [{
        "dir": "/bilder/ < filnamn.filextension >"
    }, {
        "dir": "/bilder/ < filnamn2.filextension >"
    }],
    "om boken": "denna är jättebra bok, kul"
}
```

]

Comment: Try to include blog type as grouping key and in the project stage. Something lilke this `db.morgan.aggregate({ $group: {_id:"$bloggtyp", kommentarer: {$sum: "$kommentarer"}}}, {$project: {_id:0, bloggtyp:"$_id", kommentarer: "$kommentarer"}})`

Comment: Fantastic, yes that did work great! Thank you